# Are there specific classes of functions that preserve metric topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What properties of functions preserve the topology of standard metric, such that $f(|x-y|)=d_2(x,y)$?

One example is $d_2(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ where $f(d) = \frac{d}{1+d}$, but can that statement be made more general to allow $f$ to be any continuous function? Or any differentiable function? Or any bijective function over $[0. \infty)$? Or otherwise, what set of known conditions?

Comment: Is this all happening on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I would assume so, I don't know what other kind of number an absolute value would give you.

Answer (score 1):

Two metrics are equivalent iff they have the same convergent sequences with the same limits. Hence if $f(|x-y|)$ is  a metric then it is equivalent to the usual metric iff $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t)=0$ and, conversely,  $f(t) \to 0$ implies $t \to 0$.

$f(|x-y|)$ is a metric if it satisfies the following conditions:

$f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$,

$f(x)=0$ iff $x=0$

$f$ is non-decreasing

$f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$.